# Column operations on matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have an invertible $n \times n -$matrix $A=[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$ and an invertible  $n \times n -$matrix $B=[b_1,\ldots,b_n]$. We can with column operations turn both matrices into diagonal form: $A \thicksim diag[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n]$ and $B \thicksim diag[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n]$. We also have diagonal form for product $AB \thicksim diag[\gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_n].$

How to show that that $$\prod_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \beta_i=\prod_{i=1}^n \gamma_i.$$

But don't use the (difficult) fact $\det A \det B=\det(AB)$, since I'm interested in matrix product and column operations. Is there any easy proof?

**EXAMPLE:**

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 2 & 0\\1 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 3 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1\\2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix} \quad\text{and} \quad AB = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 2\\2 & 3 & 3\\4 & 5 & 5\end{pmatrix}.$$

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 2 & 0\\1 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\thicksim \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}0 & 3 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1\\2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix} \thicksim \begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & -2/3\end{pmatrix}$

and $ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 2\\2 & 3 & 3\\4 & 5 & 5\end{pmatrix}\thicksim \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -3 & 0\\0 & 0 & -2/3\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Is swapping columns an elementary column operation?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp No, only adding scalar multiplications of columns into another columns.

Comment: Then this is false.

Comment: OK. How easy it is to see it?

Comment: I was thinking falsely. However, I am still wondering.

Comment: Do take your time :)

Comment: First, just leave away the $\alpha$s and $\beta$s. Set everything in the diagonal matrices to one which is not zero. Elementary column operations... ;o)

Comment: Saldy that won't work with arbitrary matrices ;o)

Answer (score 0):

It's false. As a counterexample, consider
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\3 & 4\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Also if you assume that $A$ and $B$ are invertible, the claim is false. A counterexample is
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 2 & 0\\1 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 3 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1\\2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
To bring $A$ to diagonal form, combine $a_1$ and $a_2$ to get $e_1$, then $e_1$ and $a_2$ to get a zero at position $(1,2)$ and then columns 2 and 3 to get $e_2$ in the second column. The procedure for $B$ is similar (here, combine $b_1$ and $b_3$ to get $e_1$). Now,
$$
C := AB = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 2\\2 & 3 & 3\\4 & 5 & 5\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have $c_2-c_3 = e_1$. Thus, no combination of $c_1$ (multiplied with non-zero scalar) with $c_2$ and $c_3$ can result in $e_1$. So, $AB$ cannot be brought to diagonal form.

Note that, however, the claim is true for invertible $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: @Juho I edited. The claim is false.

Comment: Edit again. I clarified my post.

Comment: I don't like this. Actually, it took me some time to come up with these counterexamples. And now, they don't fit because you weren't able to pose your question as it was supposed to be. And you still did not write that $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be invertible. Moreover, your claim, as it stands, is definitely false. You can further apply elementary column operations to turn the diagonal forms of $A$ and $B$ to the identity matrix.

Comment: Sorry if you feel bad. I wrote my original post when I was tired. But can you show me the elementary column operations that equal:

$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\thicksim \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$ I really can't find that.

Comment: So, mulitplying columns with numbers does not count as elementary column operation for you? I think, you should clarify what an elementary column operation is for you.

Comment: Then I mulitply some column by 2 and the other by zero, add the results and put it in the first column that I multiplied by 2.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{22}\end{pmatrix}\thicksim \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}+k \cdot a_{11}\\a_{21} & a_{22}+k \cdot a_{21}\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryRowandColumnOperations.html So, you only allow no 2.

Comment: You are right. Column operations that I ment are not elementary. Adding a multiple of one column to another is the correct one.

Comment: It *is* an elementary operation - but only a special one.

Comment: In your first example (in the question), how do you get $e_1$ in the first column?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 2 & 0\\1 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\thicksim \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \thicksim \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \thicksim \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Then$$\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: No, that's not "adding a multiple of one column to another".

Comment: Ok, I see. Very, very limited.

Comment: Indeed it is. And if you wish, you can return to my original question. Maybe there is an easy solution, I don't know.

Comment: No thanks, since you did not even upvote my efforts.

Comment: Mein liebe freund: I upvote every useful answer  _o/

Comment: Ok, I'm out, kid...